# Removing all fuzzy entries of a PO file

Tags: translation, edit, gettext, po

Does anyone know a method to mass delete all fuzzy translations from a PO file. Something like:

if #, fuzzy == TRUE Then SET msgstr="" AND REMOVE #, fuzzy

Comment: You need to go into more detail, I think.

Comment: What details do you miss, Tom?

Comment: Maybe this additional info helps: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/PO-Files.html

Comment: It looked like it might be too vague a question, but I wasn't sure if I should flag it, so I asked. I don't know gettext, but someone who does should be able to help you. It looks like they should be manipulated with gettext, so I'm reluctant to write a Python script to do it.

Comment: Yeah that was my thought too, write a script to do it, but I was wondering if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: nearly 5 years later, but did you consider simply disabling fuzzy matching during PO generation? `--no-fuzzy-matching` option for msgmerge does that

Comment: I thought that wasn't an option for me for me at the time. But I really cannot remember why anymore. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can remove fuzzy strings with [polib](https://github.com/izimobil/polib), which is THE library in Python for working with gettext po files:

```py
import os, polib
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/path/to/your/project/'):
    for filename in filenames:
        try: ext = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
        except: ext = ''
        if ext == 'po':
            po = polib.pofile(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
            for entry in po.fuzzy_entries():
                entry.msgstr = ''
                if entry.msgid_plural: entry.msgstr_plural[0] = ''
                if entry.msgid_plural and 1 in entry.msgstr_plural: entry.msgstr_plural[1] = ''
                if entry.msgid_plural and 2 in entry.msgstr_plural: entry.msgstr_plural[2] = ''
                entry.flags.remove('fuzzy')
            po.save()
```

This script removes the fuzzy translation strings + fuzzy flags, but keeps the untranslated original msgids intact. Some languages (ru, cz, ...) have more than two plural forms, therefore, we check on msgstr_plural[2]. With older versions of polib, the index to `msgstr_plural` is a string, so this would become `msgstr_plural['2']`.

Comment: Fully rewritten answer that should do exactly what you are looking for. You've probably solved the issue by now, but maybe anyone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 20):

If gettext is installed you can use the msgattrib command to accomplish this:

> msgattrib --clear-fuzzy --empty -o /path/to/output.po /path/to/input.po

The full documentation for msgattrib is here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgattrib-Invocation.html

Comment: --empty seems to be a new option for this. Today, this should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, that gives me an "invalid multibyte sequence" error, even if the PO files have UTF8 set as encoding....

Comment: Careful. It apperars that the msgid="" which contains the header/metadata, can be flagged as fuzzy. And then guess what happens if you run the above command. Yep - brains not included in this whole stuff....

#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
<all kind of important metadata, such as encoding>
...

Answer (score 8):

If you have GNU gettext installed then you can use this command to remove fuzzy messages:

> msgattrib --no-fuzzy -o path/to/your/output/po/file path/to/your/input/po/file

Comment: this removing fuzzy elements, but question is for set empty msgstr for that, i searching solution for that too, this is not correct.

Comment: How about doing `msgattrib --no-fuzzy` followed by `msgmerge` with the template? That should bring back empty messages from the template.

Comment: This removes fuzzy entries. OP wants to clear fuzzy translations and remove the fuzzy flag, but keep the entries.