# Alowing 'fuzzy' translations in django pages?

Tags: python, django, gettext, django-i18n

[I've done some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328185/django-i18n-common-causes-for-translations-not-appearing) and found that django translations don't show up when a string is marked as "fuzzy".

However, I haven't been able to find any documentation on whether I can override this behaviour.

Is there a Django setting that can be used to allow Django [(or gettext)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Fuzzy-Entries.html) to use "fuzzy translations"?

---

I know a lot of the automated translations won't be perfect, but this is for demonstration, development and testing for an open-source product.

I'd rather have users be able to develop in their own language with "approximate" translations then use that as an incentive to check them off as they go.

Answer (score 20):

It would be unfortunate to show these translations as some of them are most certainly wrong.  You are supposed to remove the fuzzy tag when you update the translations and revise the guessed translations that are marked as fuzzy.

However, you may run a tool to quickly delete the fuzzy markers from a `.po` file: [Removing all fuzzy entries of a PO file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372414/removing-all-fuzzy-entries-of-a-po-file)

---

### UPDATE

Here is a great overview of the GNU gettext work-flow: https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Overview

It is msgfmt that strips the fuzzy translations.  It has an option `--use-fuzzy` that includes the fuzzy translations.

`msgfmt` is wrapped by `compilemessages` django admin command, which since version 1.8 has the `--use-fuzzy` option too (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#compilemessages)

Comment: Its mostly for testing and demonstration purposes. I'll add some more details.

Comment: The answer you were hoping for, like a debug setting like `USE_FUZZY_TRANSLATIONS = True` aint going to happen, because the fuzzy translations arent in the files (`.mo`) from which the translations are read. Your last change to fix this is when you run `compilemessages`.

Comment: No. It seems not, but compiling for Dec is close enough. Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: Note to readers: this used to be the accepted answer, until OP ragequit and attempted to punish bystanders for their [political disagreement with Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342994) in the process. Feel free to throw it an upvote to compensate if you like ;-)